# What's wrong with this <form #clientForm="ngForm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit(clientForm)">

Tags: angular, forms, compilation, angular-forms

I am getting an error from this:

```
<form #clientForm="ngForm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit(clientForm)">
```

The error message is:

```
src/app/components/add-client/add-client.component.html:18:44 - error TS2339: Property 'onSubmit' does not exist on type 'AddClientComponent'.
    
18  <form #clientForm="ngForm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit(clientForm)">
                                                  ~~~~~~~~
    
src/app/components/add-client/add-client.component.ts:7:16
7   templateUrl: './add-client.component.html',
                         ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

The error occurs in the template of the component AddClientComponent.

Comment: you has not a function `onSubmit` in your .ts. check the upper and lower case -Angular is case sensitive-

Comment: Thank you very much. I am a newbie and doing an angular course (angular front to  back) which is outdated. Anyway the ts file looks like this: import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Client } from '../../models/Client';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-add-client',
  templateUrl: './add-client.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./add-client.component.css']
})
 export class AddClientComponent implements OnInit {
     client: Client = {
    firstName: '',    lastName: '',    email: '',    phone: '',    balance: 0
  }
     constructor(){}


ngOnInit(){
    }
  }

Comment: Don't put code in comments. [edit] the post and put the code there.

Comment: @ClausAndresen, when you write in an html tag some like `(ngSubmit)="...."` or `(click)="..."`, you're using [event binding](https://angular.io/guide/event-binding). You need write a function in .ts. e.g.:`onSubmit(form:any){console.log(form)}`